# mysql cell values with dates as new columns with years

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that looks like this:

```
|id  | city  |  created  |
|1   | city1 |2011-12-10 |
|2   | city2 |2010-02-01 |
|3   | city3 |2009-12-03 |
|4   | city1 |2012-11-16 |
|5   | city2 |2012-08-03 |
|6   | city3 |2011-10-01 |
|7   | city1 |2009-10-02 |
|8   | city2 |2011-12-01 |
|9   | city3 |2012-06-30 |
```

But I want to have an alternate table or view that looks like this

```
|city  | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 |
|city1 |   1  |  0   | 1    | 1    |
|city2 |   0  |  1   | 1    | 1    |
|city3 |   1  |  1   | 0    | 1    |
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) AS requests, city, YEAR(created) as year
FROM enquiries
GROUP BY city

I'm having problems to separate the years as different columns. I actually don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    YourTable.city,
    SUM(IF(YEAR(created)=2009,1,0)) AS '2009',
    SUM(IF(YEAR(created)=2010,1,0)) AS '2010',
    SUM(IF(YEAR(created)=2011,1,0)) AS '2011',
    SUM(IF(YEAR(created)=2012,1,0)) AS '2012'
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    YourTable.city
```

Comment: This worked if you added a parenthesis before AS but it's not very dynamic. Is it possible so that it automatic detects if a year is present and creates a column for it?

Comment: I think only with dynamic sql. This would be so easy if you would have used MSSQL 2005+.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
select 
    city,
    sum(case when year(created) = 2009 then 1 else 0 end) as 2009,
    sum(case when year(created) = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) as 2010,
    sum(case when year(created) = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) as 2011,
    sum(case when year(created) = 2012 then 1 else 0 end) as 2012
from
    enquiries
group by city
```